# React native how to access data variable globally for all screen explain with simple program

Tags: react-native

I want to set data variable globally and I have to update from any page (some of us saying redux can anyone please explain with simple program ?)

Answer (score 1):

See with redux , varibales stored globally are called state, and it sits at the root level. Suppose you create a state object in a reducer :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  phoneNum: '',

}
```

and when you dispatch actions from your component, you can actually change its value by like `dispatch({type:'CHange phone',value:7973913});`

And you can dispatch from any any component, and it will trigger the change of phoneNum and even you can access anywhere like suppose `this.state.loginReducer.phoneNum`

You can check this link [react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) for detailed info which are portrayed beautifully.

Hope it help.s